# Getting started with SharpMap in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, references, visual-studio, sharpmap, documentation

I am trying to use SharpMap in Visual Studio with C#.
My first step was to go to the Tutorials on CodePlex.

https://archive.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharpMap%20Tutorial&referringTitle=Home

But that is a broken link, as are *all* the links on the CodePlex page for SharpMap.

I found another tutorial.  The first step to make a map window worked well, but the second step:

https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap/wiki/Adding-a-layer-to-the-Map

failed to produce any image in the map window.  (I carefully followed the instructions and do have the data file extracted and correctly referenced.)

I have no idea what to try next.

**Is there any documentation for SharpMap?**  I've not been able to find any.

My application is to display of the NOAA Nautical charts.